# including rails object in meta tags keywords

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, metadata

I'd like to include a rails object in my keywords as well as straight text but the code is clearly not the right way to do it...how can I do this?

```
set_meta_tags :keywords => %w[keyword1 keyword2 #{params[:hospital]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at two plug-ins for including rails object in meta tags:

Meta Magic: https://github.com/lassebunk/metamagic

Head Liner: https://github.com/mokolabs/headliner

**Edit: For Meta tag gem**

What I usually do is write a meta helper that I simply stick in my `ApplicationHelper`, that looks like this:

```
def meta(field = nil, list = [])
  field = field.to_s
  @meta ||= {
    'robots' => ['all'],
    'copyright' => ['My Copyright'],
    'content-language' => ['en'],
    'title' => [],
    'keywords' => []
  }

  if field.present?
    @meta[field] ||= []
    case list.class
      when Array then
        @meta[field] += list
      when String then
        @meta[field] += [list]
      else
        @meta[field] += [list]
    end

    case field
      when 'description' then
        content = truncate(strip_tags(h(@meta[field].join(', '))), :length => 255)
      else
        content = @meta[field].join(', ')
    end

    return raw(%(<meta #{att}="#{h(field)}" content="#{h(content)}"/>))
  else
    tags = ''
    @meta.each do |field, list|
      tags += meta(field)+"\n"
    end
    return tags.rstrip
  end
end
```

You can simply set meta tags in your views, by adding a call to `meta()` in it. So in an `articles/show.html.erb` you might add this to the top of your view:

```
<% meta(:title, @article.title) %>
```

And in your layouts, you add it without any parameters, so it'll spit out the meta tags.

```
<%= meta %>
```

Or have it output an individual tag:

```
<%= meta(:title) %>
```

I bet you there's more elegant solutions, though.

But if you were looking for something already implemented in Rails you're out of luck.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks - I'm using meta-tags gem.  It's an issue of how to put the rails object into the keywords...

Comment: keywords and meta tags are deprecated these days, having good content on your pages will be just as if not more effective. The major Search engine providers ignore them...

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your view as it worked for me (using meta-tags gem):

```
<% keywords [[@modelname.keyword1], [@modelname.keyword2]] %>
```

and you cad additional keywords in text format by adding them within the ruby in the following format `['keyword3']`